# Affixing an angled shelf to a wall

Tags: shelving, interior, brackets

I want to build a 45 degree angled shelf (think along the lines of a magazine shelf) across a 4 metre plasterboard covered concrete wall. The target load is approx. 50kg distributed evenly.

[image: example angled shelf]

I haven't bought any of the materials yet, but I'm considering getting some of [these laminated chipboard panels](http://www.jewson.co.uk/timber/sheet-materials/chipboard/standard-chipboard/products/FFCWH245/alexander-cleghorn-melamine-chipboard-white-15-x-457-x-2440mm/). My initial plan was to purchase a set of 45 degree angled metal brackets and fix them at 1 metre intervals, to compensate for the front-heavy weight distribution.

So far I've had no luck sourcing shelf brackets that are anything other than 90 degrees. I did find some ["adjustable" brackets](http://www.wickes.co.uk/Wickes-3-Position-Heavy-Duty-Bracket-400x270mm/p/165031) that appeared to do what I want; but having looked at them close up in a Wickes store I've determined they don't tilt enough for my need and they look a bit too "industrial" for an in-home shelf.

My question is, how should I affix this shelf to the wall? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Adjustable brackets should do. Other possibilities include experimenting with perforated steel profiles, but it need some degree of knowledge (or experience) to make this by yourself. As for panels bearing of load - the 45 deg. placement should actually help (vertical heigth of section) as well as this bottom narrow panel (a barrier?).

Comment: Hi Marek, thanks for your thoughts. I continued searching for an appropriate adjustable wall bracket with a 45° position, but no success there. I did find a [tap-in style bracket](http://www.staples.com/Econoco-GC10-10-Adjustable-Tap-In-Style-Shelf-Bracket-Metal-Chrome/product_218360) that looks promising; but I'm now considering options for a DIY wood bracket, as my planned shelf load isn't huge and they would be easier to conceal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I decided to post an answer as some images and more text will follow)
As I wrote in comment, adjustable brackets will be ok for you. The problem is the price and, personally, I would never spend 35$ on it (as some example were given).  What are other choices? DYI 45 deg. angle brackets:

**1. Fast track to success: try to find something that suits your case.**
Sometimes you can buy parts that will work the same placed differently. Take a look at this IKEA bracket:
[image: IKEA bracket]

This one, used conversly and using proper bolts with washers to ensure that it will not fall down, will do the work. Make additional holes on this 45 deg. edge and it will make your day. Of course, you can use other ones:
[image]
like this wooden, full-section. You just need to find proper angle (the one on the image is rather not suitable.
Given both example above, you will know what to look for. Just mind that you will also need to think over the attachement - this differs case by case. I'm sure you can handle that.

**2. Steep road to become DIY master.**
Similar way to the first one, but with use of some DIY skills and additional stuff. Let's consider following brackets:
 - wooden one:
[image]
- steel one:
[image]
As in previous approach - use them conversly, but this time (to make it work with shelves) combine it with some steel parts:
[image]
[image]
The L-shaped steel part (actually you would need a much smaller one) can be bended a little (90->135) to match angle and to be attached to bracket. As for the steep band - it can be customized in various ways to make same clips as the L-shape and to make a connector bracket<->shelf with correct angle.
If something is not clear here, just comment it and I will try to provide more description. Good luck!

Comment: Some good well articulated ideas here, thanks! Particularly interested in the IKEA bracket, I'll take a closer look at those.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a custom made wooden bracket (but then I'm a carpenter!) but you could try searching the 'shop fitting' or 'point-of-sale' industries as they have all kind of different display related stuff. I searched for "POS display shelf brackets" and saw a few different brackets. 
Just a thought...

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've found some POS tap-in adjustable brackets but a little concerned about the weight they can handle. I'll keep looking...